# Array_key_exist of matching keyword

Tags: php, yii

I have an array as follows stored in variable **$keyword_reports_data**

```
[interne] => Array
             (
                [Google.ca - Canada] => Array (...) 
                [Google.com - USA] => Array (...)
             )
```

i have code like this to search(not exactly for example)

```
foreach ($keyword_reports_data['interne'] as $key => $value) {
   if (array_key_exists("Google.ca", $value)) {
      echo "hi " ;exit;
   }   
   else {
      echo  "not exist "; exit;
   }
}
```

But actually it will print

> not exist

how to print "hi" if array value exist like keyword "Google.ca" only with `"Google.ca" not with "Google.ca - Canada"` so i need to put condition for this

Comment: In your example, `Google.ca` does not exist as an array key. `Google.ca - Canada` is an array key.

Comment: @JustBaron the search above, looks for a key within the sub arrays.  Data that is left to our imagination.

Comment: @Progrock agreed, missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key differs within the array. Change the key from `"Google.ca"` to `"Google.ca - Canada"`.

### Exact match

If you want to match the key *exactly*, use `array_key_exists`.

Change the if statement to:

```
if (array_key_exists("Google.ca - Canada", $value)) {
```

### Partial match

If you want to check whether the key contains part of a string, either use `preg_match` or `strpos`. Regular expressions *can* be slow, hence the suggestion of using `strpos`.

Examples below:

#### preg_match

```
if (preg_match('/Google.ca/', $key)) {
```

https://3v4l.org/CcMt7

#### strpos

```
if (strpos($key, 'Google.ca') === 0) {
```

https://3v4l.org/QB1kT

*Note: we're checking to see if the beginning of the string matches `Google.ca`, using `===`.*

Comment: Sorry may be my question you dont understand ....i need to print hi .....with keyword "Google.ca" not "Google.ca - Canada"

Comment: `array_key_exists` will match the value. Are you trying to check whether the key contains `Google.ca`?

Comment: You'll need to use regex, I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: if (array_key_exists("Google.ca - Canada", $value))  this is working i know but another two

Comment: i cant change key because its huge from live databse

Comment: The code doesn't change keys. Click the links above to see how the code works.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/CcMt7 and https://3v4l.org/QB1kT are both working for me.

Comment: How to unset this key from the array

Comment: `unset($keyword_reports_data['interne'][$key])` should work. (For reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to search the key (not value) for a substring in your loop.

```
$data = [
    'animals' => [
        'UK sheep' => ['beltex', 'blackface'],
        'UK pigs'  => ['berkshire', 'duroc'],
        'NZ sheep' => ['corriedale'],
    ]
];

foreach($data['animals'] as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key,'UK') === 0) {
        echo "A key found beginning with 'UK'.\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    A key found beginning with 'UK'.
    A key found beginning with 'UK'.
```